# Click a circle and make it the size of the section/div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi there I was wondering if it was possible so that when you click on a circle that it expands to fill the section/div that it is in?

I want that so when you click the circle it fills the screen and then some text appears in its place.

Before I posted this I took one more look on the web and found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scriptedpixels/LRUNx/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=LRUNx)

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="ObjectContainer">
        <div id="red" class="Object"></div>
        <a href="#" >A link </a>
    </div>

    <div class="ObjectContainer">
        <div id="brown" class="Object"></div>
        <a href="#" >A link </a>
    </div>

    <div class="ObjectContainer">
        <div id="dGrey" class="Object"></div>
        <a href="#" >A link </a>
    </div>

    <div class="ObjectContainer">
        <div id="Grey" class="Object"></div>
        <a href="#" >A link </a>
    </div>

</div>

body {
            text-align:center;
            font-family:helvetica;
            font-size: 16px;
            background: #f0f0f0;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
            a {
                color: #f0f0f0;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        .container {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 400px;
        }
        /* ANIMATIONS */
        .Object, .ObjectContainer a {
            -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        }
        .ObjectContainer {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
            .ObjectContainer .Object {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .ObjectContainer a {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: -200px;
                left: 0;
                opacity: 0;
                width: 100%;
                line-height: 0px;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

        .ObjectContainer:hover .Object {
            margin: 2.5%;
            height: 95%;
            width: 95%;
            border-radius: 100px;
            /* -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(100deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(100deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(100deg);
            transform: rotate(100deg); */
        }
            .ObjectContainer:hover a {
                opacity: 1;
                bottom: 0;
                line-height: 200px;
            }
        #red.Object {
            background: #e7222f;
        }
        #brown.Object {
            background: #796959;
        }
        #dGrey.Object {
            background: #363635;
        }
        #Grey.Object {
            background: #6f6f6e;
        }
```

It is what I am looking for but the opposite way round.

**Edit**

I have more and less got it now by messing about with what yous have given me. Here is the link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scriptedpixels/LRUNx/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=LRUNx)

All I have done was sawp about the code. I didn't even think of this at the start. I still need to work on the text layout (needs more spaced out) and might try to do it with a click base event.

```
   #red.Object {
    background: #e7222f;
    margin: 2.5%;
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
  #red.Object:hover {
    background: #e7222f;
         margin: 2.5%;
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read SO rules, Zack? SO is about improving your own programming skills, not about others coding for you for free. Have you made an attempt at coding this yourself?

Comment: Hi Zack, welcome to SO.  Can you post what you've tried so far, so we can help you improve it?  (Copying someone else's efforts and asking us to fix them isn't a great way to learn :) )

Comment: @Steve  I did try it myself first but didn't get that far. I had only change a couple of lines of code, so saw no point in posting it instead of his. Next time I will post mine thought. Thanks :)

Comment: @ZackReid cool!  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the top two circles and is this the desired starting results you were looking for?

```
body {
        text-align:center;
        font-family:helvetica;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: #f0f0f0;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
        a {
            color: #f0f0f0;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    .container {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 400px;
    }
    /* ANIMATIONS */
    .Object, .ObjectContainer a {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }
    .ObjectContainer {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
        .ObjectContainer .Object {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .ObjectContainer a {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -200px;
            left: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

    .ObjectContainer:hover .Object {
        margin: 2.5%;
        height: 95%;
        width: 95%;
        border-radius: 100px;
        /* -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(100deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(100deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(100deg);
        transform: rotate(100deg); */
    }
        .ObjectContainer:hover a {
            opacity: 1;
            bottom: 0;
            line-height: 200px;
        }
    #red.Object {
        background: #e7222f;
        margin: 2.5%;
        height: 95%;
        width: 95%;
        border-radius: 100px;
    }
    #brown.Object {
        background: #796959;
        margin: 2.5%;
        height: 95%;
        width: 95%;
        border-radius: 100px;
    }
    #dGrey.Object {
        background: #363635;
    }
    #Grey.Object {
        background: #6f6f6e;
    }
```

Comment: Yea this is the starting point that I want. Then when you click on them it fill the section/ div. While the text appears also. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: I used your why but changed it about a bit. It still needs for though but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){

$('#circle').click(function(){
  var pw = $('#wrapper').width();
  var ph = $('#wrapper').height();
  $(this).animate({
    width: pw,
    height: ph,
    borderRadius: 0
  },500)
});

});
```

```css
#wrapper{

width: 300px;
height: 300px;  
background: lightgrey;
}

#circle{
position: absolute;
width: 45px;  
height: 45px;
background: green;  
border-radius: 50%;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  
  <div id="circle"></div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying not to use jquery, sorry for not stating that in the question. But thanks for another example of how it can be done :)

Answer (score 1):

Some quick hacks into your fiddle (shew!)

**snippet below**

```js
function clicker(e){
 //console.log(e.target.tagName);
  var width=window.getComputedStyle(e.target,null)||e.target.currentStyle;
  if(e.target.tagName=='DIV'){
   if(width.borderBottomLeftRadius!='0px'){
  e.target.style='width:100%;height:100%;border-radius:0px;'; 
  e.target.children[0].style='opacity: 1;bottom: 100px;line-height: -20px;';
}
  else{
     e.target.style='width:95%;height:95%;border-radius:100px';
       e.target.children[0].style='opacity: 1;bottom: 0px;line-height: 0px;';
  }
  } //endif
 
}
function add(x){
  document.getElementsByClassName('ObjectContainer')[x].addEventListener('click',clicker,true)
}
for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('ObjectContainer').length;++i){
  add(i);
}
```

```css
/* setup the very basis for the document */
    body {
            text-align:center;
            font-family:helvetica;
            font-size: 16px;
            background: #f0f0f0;
            padding-top: 50px;
    }
            a {
                    color: #f0f0f0;
                    text-decoration: none;
            }
    .container {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 400px;
    }
    /* ANIMATIONS */
    .Object, .ObjectContainer a, .test {
            -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition:  0.25s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }
    .ObjectContainer {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
    }
    
            .ObjectContainer a {
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: -200px;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    line-height: 0px;
                    text-align: center;
                    vertical-align: middle;
            }

    .ObjectContainer .Object  {
      
            margin: 2.5%;
            height: 95%;
            width: 95%;
            border-radius: 100px;
            /* -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(100deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(100deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(100deg);
            transform: rotate(100deg); */
    }

    #red.Object {
            background: #e7222f;
    }
    #brown.Object {
            background: #796959;
    }
    #dGrey.Object {
            background: #363635;
    }
    #Grey.Object {
            background: #6f6f6e;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="ObjectContainer">
            <div id="red" class="Object"> <a href="#" >A link </a></div>
           
    </div>
    
    <div class="ObjectContainer">
            <div id="brown" class="Object"> <a href="#" >A link </a></div>
           
    </div>

    <div class="ObjectContainer">
            <div id="dGrey" class="Object"> <a href="#" >A link </a></div>
           
    </div>

    <div class="ObjectContainer">
            <div id="Grey" class="Object"> <a href="#" >A link </a></div>
           
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I was just wondering how you could make it go back to a circle if you click it again? I added in a mouseover thinking it would reset if I unhover. Then lastly why is the text not appearing anymore? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: But thinking about it I think clicking the circle would work better for the user as they can control it easier.

Comment: Sorry to reply a bit late (was at work)...answer edited to make div do the opposite when clicked again..enjoy..:D

Comment: No problem man.. Thanks again for the response, but when I run your code snippet it doesn't work. I will see I can fix it though. Thanks for the help and hope you enjoy your night :)